# How to show images from Database with flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I'm working on a project with some friends and we're doing a basketball championship website were anybody can create an account, that account will have a default image when created, but my problem is how to display that image on the page. Here's what I'm trying to do now:

(some words are in portugese)

querys.py:

Storing the picture in a variable

```
from matplotlib import image as img

foto_perfil = img.imread("website\static\img\pngwing.com.png")
```

when the account is created the picture is stored in the DB (it's working)

```
`def inserir_conta_jogador(email, password, coach, player):
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    inserir_conta_no_banco = cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO conta (email, password, coach, player, picture) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (email, password, coach, player, picture))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    cursor.close()`
```

From now on I don't know if any of these is working

getting the picture("foto") from the db

```
def get_foto(id):
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    get_foto = cursor.execute(""" SELECT foto FROM conta WHERE id = %s""", [id])
    get_foto_fecth = cursor.fetchone()
    return get_foto
```

getting the picture from the user that's logged in and storing it as "foto" for the HTML page

```
@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if "user_id" in session:
        user = session["user_id"]
        foto = get_foto(user)
        return render_template("index.html", user=user, foto=foto)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Displaying at the page:

```
{% if user %}
  <h1> ID LOGGED: {{ user }}</h1>
  <img src="{{foto}}">
  {% else %}
  <h1> NOBODY LOGGED IN </h1>
  {% endif %}
```

When I go to the page the image is not shown

What should I change in my code?

Show the image at the page

Comment: you need to store it as base64 data url in order to do this ... why not just save to disk? generally storing photos in a database as binary blobs is not desirable ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm kinda new to all of this, do you mean to save all profiles pictures at my disk? I thought that saving at the DB was the easy way

Comment: its not so much that its hard as that it is inefficient ... in theory (hopefully) you are using a blob type for the file... which iirc in mysql is converting that to base64data ... then when you fetch it it is converting back to binary...but in order to show it you need to have a base64 data-url (or a link to an uploaded file on disk that is reachable via a web route)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need matplotlib at all

```
import base64
with open("/path/to/img.png","rb") as f:
    data_uri = f"data:image/png;base64,{base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()}"
    print(data_uri)
    # test by copy pasting data_uri into your browser
    # save data_uri somewhere (it does not have to be blob since it is now text)
```

then later

```
<img src={{data_uri}} />
```

but I would recommend following [flasks file upload guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/fileuploads/) and not saving the images in the database and using the `File` database model type